# Executing gasless transaction using etherjs and openzeppelin

Tags: ethers.js, openzeppelin, meta-transactions, gasless

My objective is simple I want to send a gasless transaction from one address to another. I am providing the code below.

I am using openzeppelin Defender relayer to cover the gas prices of the transaction

```
const { DefenderRelayProvider,DefenderRelaySigner } = require('@openzeppelin/defender-relay-     client/lib/ethers');

const { ethers } = require('ethers');

async function sendGaslessTransaction() {
// Instantiate the DefenderRelayProvider
const credentials = {
apiKey: 'Relayer Api Key',
apiSecret: 'Relayer Api secret'
};

const provider = new DefenderRelayProvider(credentials);


const senderPrivateKey = 'private key';

// Gasless transaction parameters
const transaction = {
to: 'Recipient address',  
value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0005"),
gasLimit: 21000
};

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(senderPrivateKey);

const signedTransaction = await wallet.signTransaction(transaction);

console.log("signed transaction",signedTransaction)

const relayerSignedTransaction = {
    to: beneficiaryAddress.toLowerCase(),
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0005").toHexString(), // Amount to transfer in wei
    gasLimit: 30000,
    data: signedTransaction
  };

// Instantiate the DefenderRelaySigner

const signer = new DefenderRelaySigner(credentials, provider, { speed: 'fast' });

// Populate the transaction with additional details
const populatedTransaction = await signer.populateTransaction(relayerSignedTransaction);

// Send the gasless transaction to the relayer for execution and gas fee payment 
try {
const response = await signer.sendTransaction(populatedTransaction);
console.log('Transaction hash:', response.transactionHash);

} catch (error) {
console.error('Error sending gasless transaction:', error);
}
}

sendGaslessTransaction();
```

In a gasless transaction, funds are transferred from AddressA to AddressB and the relayer pays the gas fees of this transaction. The same is my objective but in the code provided the funds are transferring from the relayer account to AddressB instead it should transfer from AddressA and the relayer should only cover the gas price.

The problem I think is in the Defender Relayer Signer class it is using the relayer to sign and send the transaction and ignoring the wallet generated using the private key of address A.

Additionally, I have seen that many tutorials and resources are using smart contracts for this purpose but I want to execute the transaction without implementing any smart contract

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is your relayer to sponsor your transaction without signing it, by signing the transaction yourself instead.

Unfortunately, I think there is no any way to do that without sending 2 transactions.

1. Your relayer fund your account with the estimated gas cost of the transaction.
2. You send the transaction from your wallet.

The order of the operations depends on the design but those are the txs you need.

For more info about sponsored transactions you can check https://www.erc4337.io/